# Fibonacci sequence and nth number with reduce()

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

```
const generateFibonnaciSequence = (n) => {
    return [
        (arr = new Array(n).fill(1).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
            arr.push(i <= 1 ? 1 : arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1]);
            return arr;
        }, [])),
        arr[n - 1],
    ];
};

const [fibonacciSequence, fibonacciNthNumber] = generateFibonnaciSequence(n);
```

My idea is to return an array holding fibonacci sequence up to `n` in index 0 and fibonnaci's n-th value in index 1. Can someone help me with a prettier way of constructing this function. I'd like to avoid holding the array in temp arr variable if possible, but still use a single expression for return statement.

Comment: Code Reviews -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: where should `arr` go? do you really need `reduce`? btw, `arr` is a global variable. if not needed, just `pop` the last value.

Comment: This code suffers from "too-clever-itis"; it tries to do too much in one line and suffers for it. Just use more than one line, make your statements (and variable names) clear. Save boiling it down to less code to minifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using recursion with tail call optimization. This code shouldn't have problems with fib(1000) and more

```js
function fib(n){
let result=new Array(2);
result[0]="0 ";
result[1] = fibImp(0,1,n);

   return result;

function fibImp(a,b,n){
  if(n===0)
    return a;
    
  result[0] += b+" ";
  return fibImp(b,a+b,n-1);
}

}

[sequence, result] = fib(8);
console.log(sequence);
console.log(result);
```